# What book should I read as an alternative to "Head First Servlets and JSP"?

Tags: java, servlets

I am looking for another book beside [Head First Servlets and JSP](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005405). The Head First book didn't really appeal too me, as it was too much theory and questions/exam objectives.

I am looking something along the lines of [RailSpace: Building a Social Networking Website with Ruby on Rails](http://railsspace.com/). Something that involves me writing a lot of code and would "wake me up" for a real world web application project. That might be asking for a lot, but you get my direction :) Answers are much appreciated.

> **Related:**
>   [Best Java book you have read so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102/best-java-book-you-have-read-so-far)

Comment: I'm sure you can find numerous resources in "Best Java book you have read so far," http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102/best-java-book-you-have-read-so-far

Comment: @Jonathan: "HF Servlets and JSP" covers a much different (more focused) set of information than most general books on Java.  I think this is specific enough to survive on its own (of course, the community can always outvote me on this).

Comment: @Bill No problem. Nice edits to you and Shog9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Murach's Servlet book is very good, [Murach's Java Servlets and JSP, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1890774448)

Comment: Thank you very much, got this book right away and the content seems to cover a lot. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I like the ones from sun blue prints - Core Servlets and Javaserver Pages: Core Technologies, Vol. 1 (2nd Edition)

Amazon [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130092290)

Comment: +1: Marty Hall is good. He has also a lot of high quality online tutorials for JSP/Servlet/JSF/JSTL/Eclipse/Tomcat/etc here: http://www.coreservlets.com